# Add multiple recipients to MFMailcomposer torecepients: field - Xcode IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an existing program that enables me to 'tag' an email and add it to an ARRAY , I am then trying to use that ARRAY in my existing program and add it

array2 has had a group of email addresses added to it so consists of "something@sky.com,some@sky.com"

```
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray addObjectToArray:array2]; 

[composer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```

Please don't 'flame' my code or message as I am typing the above from memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *recipntNames = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *toRecipientsNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"something@sky.com",@"some@sky.com",nil];   
[recipntNames setToRecipients:toRecipientsNames];
```

or use this **array2** is your `NSMutableArray` Name

```
NSArray *array = [array2 copy];

[recipntNames setToRecipients:toRecipientsNames];
```

need more reference use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863527/cannot-send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I have actually constructed an NSMutableArray to hold data but it errors when I try and use it , you have added the 'actual email addresses ' but I need it to use the NSMutableArray as it can change

Comment: have a nice day my friend

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to you, that using [composer setToRecipients:array2] would be better :-)